# Yaml change not detected,Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

Tags: java, cassandra, yaml

I have changed Cassandra configuration file

```
cat /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml | grep -n 'seed'
416:seed_provider:
423:          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
425:          - seeds:"84.208.89.132,192.168.0.23,192.168.0.25,192.168.0.28"
```

and also cluster name

```
10:cluster_name: 'Petter Cluster'
```

I am surprised to see what the system.log shows

```
INFO  [main] 2018-01-27 17:20:51,343 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
ERROR [main] 2018-01-27 17:20:51,427 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
 Error: while parsing a block mapping; expected <block end>, but found FlowEntry;  in 'reader', line 425, column 34:
              - seeds: "192.168.0.13","192.168.0.23","192.168.0.25"," ... 
                                     ^
INFO  [main] 2018-02-03 20:35:48,528 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
ERROR [main] 2018-02-03 20:35:48,844 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
 Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=seed_provider for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@551bdc27; java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^
INFO  [main] 2018-02-03 20:39:08,311 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
ERROR [main] 2018-02-03 20:39:08,647 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
 Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=seed_provider for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@551bdc27; java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
```

How to fix this?How to initialize system after the changes?

Comment: did you restart cassandra after the .yaml file change?

Comment: sometimes you need to restart all nodes as well. Mainly for cluster name changes.

Comment: @dilsingi Yes, I restarted cassandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have got into a issue with Cluster name,it is supposed be changed on all the nodes if you willing to change it.

Here are instruction to change Cluster name :
1. Log into cqlsh
2. cqlsh> UPDATE system.local SET cluster_name = 'Petter Cluster' where key='local';  (You need to issue this command on each of the nodes where you would like to change the cluster name. )
system.local gets changed only locally
3. cqlsh> exit;
4. $ nodetool flush system
5. edit cassandra.yaml cluster name to YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME.
6. Restart cassandra.

Please check this link as well:
https://surbhinosqldba.wordpress.com/2015/07/23/how-to-rename-modify-cassandra-cluster-name/